# How to make a Tkinter frame raise from different files?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to use Tkinter to create a GUI for a school planner and I want to have users be able to log in and create an account. It might get too lengthy if I try to code the entire project in one file, so I'm trying to split it up. My main file just has:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk                # python 3
    from tkinter import font as tkfont  # python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk     # python 2
    import tkFont as tkfont  # python 2

import TkWindow

app = TkWindow.TkWindow()
app.getRoot().mainloop()
```

Where my `TkWindow` file is the file that runs everything. It looks like this:

```
from tkinter import *

import mainMenu
import CreateAccount


class TkWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.master = Tk()  # Makes the window
        self.master.wm_title("School Planner")
        self.master.config(background="#FFFFFF")

        # Master window dimensions
        app_width = 1000
        app_height = 500

        screen_width = self.master.winfo_screenwidth()  # Get screen width
        screen_height = self.master.winfo_screenheight()  # Get screen height

        x = int((screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2))  # X coordinate to center application
        y = int((screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2))  # Y coordinate to center application

        self.dimensions = f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{x}+{y}'

        self.master.geometry(self.dimensions)  # Set master geometry

        container = Frame(self.master, width=app_width, height=app_height, relief='raised', borderwidth=5)

        # self.currentFrame = Frames.main(self.master)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (mainMenu.MainMenu, CreateAccount.CreateAccount):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(master=container.master, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame

        self.show_frame("MainMenu")

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def getRoot(self):
        return self.master
```

Where my `mainMenu` file is:

```
from tkinter import *

import Fonts
import CreateAccount


class MainMenu(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.root = master
        self.root.title("Benjamin's School Planner")
        # TODO: get an icon and find the path of it
        # master.iconbitmap('HERE SHOULD GO THE FILE PATH TO THE ICON')

        # Master window dimensions
        app_width = 1000
        app_height = 500

        #screen_width = master.winfo_screenwidth()  # Get screen width
        #screen_height = master.winfo_screenheight()  # Get screen height

        #x = int((screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2))  # X coordinate to center application
        #y = int((screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2))  # Y coordinate to center application

        #master.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{x}+{y}')  # Set master geometry

        # Set and display welcome message
        welcome_label = Label(self.root, text='Welcome to the School Planner', font=Fonts.welcomeFont())
        welcome_label.pack()

        # Set and display username prompt
        username_label = Label(self.root, text='Username', font=Fonts.loginFont())
        username_label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.4, anchor='center')
        username_entry = Entry(self.root)
        username_entry.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.4, anchor='center')

        # Set and display username prompt
        password_label = Label(self.root, text='Password', font=Fonts.loginFont())
        password_label.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

        password_entry = Entry(self.root, show="\u2022")
        password_entry.place(relx=0.55, rely=0.5, anchor='center')

        # Login button command:
        def login():
            print("Logged in Successfully")

        # Login button creation:
        login_button = Button(text='Login',
                              command=lambda: login(),
                              bg='Gray', fg='Black', font=Fonts.loginFont())
        login_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.62, anchor='center')

        # 'Show Password' Checkbox creation
        checkboxVar = IntVar()

        def showPassword():
            if checkboxVar.get() == 1:
                password_entry.config(show="")
                password_entry.update()
            elif checkboxVar.get() == 0:
                password_entry.config(show="\u2022")

        show_password_checkbox = Checkbutton(master,
                                             text="Show Password",
                                             font=Fonts.showPasswordFont(),
                                             variable=checkboxVar,
                                             command=showPassword)
        show_password_checkbox.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor='center')

        # Create Account button creation:
        create_account_button = Button(text='Create Account',
                              command=lambda: controller.show_frame("CreateAccount"),
                              bg='Gray', fg='Black', font=Fonts.createAccountFont())
        create_account_button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor='center')
```

And my `CreateAccount` file is:

```
from tkinter import *

import Fonts


class CreateAccount(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        #master.title("Create Account")
        master.config(bg='blue')

        # Master window dimensions
        app_width = 1000
        app_height = 500

        #screen_width = master.winfo_screenwidth()  # Get screen width
        #screen_height = master.winfo_screenheight()  # Get screen height

        #x = int((screen_width / 2) - (app_width / 2))  # X coordinate to center application
        #y = int((screen_height / 2) - (app_height / 2))  # Y coordinate to center application

        #master.geometry(f'{app_width}x{app_height}+{x}+{y}')  # Set master geometry


        welcome_label = Label(master, text='We made it to create account', font=Fonts.welcomeFont())
        welcome_label.pack()
```

I'm having trouble where when it runs, it's running both frames at the same time at the beginning and I'm not sure why. Whenever I press the "create account" button, it registers that a frame should switch, but the new one doesn't arise. Does anyone know why?

Comment: That's way too much code for a question here — stackoverflow isn't a free debug-my-code website. Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: I don't know if it has any bearing on the problem, but I noticed there's no `frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")` following the `frame = F(master=container.master, controller=self)` in the loop creating the `self.frames` dictionary.